# Docstring has inconsistent leading whitespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, docstring

In the following code:

```
def read_file(filename):
    """
    >>> read_file('text.txt')
    {'Donald Trump': [('Donald Trump', 'Join me live in Springfield, Ohio!\nLit!!\n', 1477604720, 'Twitter for iPhone', 5251, 1895)]}
    """
```

I get an error saying:

```
ValueError: line 4 of the docstring for __main__.read_file has inconsistent leading whitespace: 'Lit!!'
```

Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: Where is the error triggered? It looks like you are running doctests. As someone already answered, the problem is those unescaped `\n` newlines in the test data. But in any case, doctests are not optimal for functions with side effects. This test will fail if `text.txt` can't be found, or the contents is different from what's expected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Escape all backslashes in the documentation string. That is:

```
\nLit!!\n
```

Should instead be:

```
\\nLit!!\\n'
```

Alternatively you could supply the docstring as a raw string and not worry about backslashes:

```
r"""
>>> read_file('text.txt')
{'Donald Trump': [('Donald Trump', 'Join me live in Springfield, Ohio!\nLit!!\n', 1477604720, 'Twitter for iPhone', 5251, 1895)]}
"""
```

Comment: right. the error is due to the fact that the `\n` is interpreted as part of the string thereby braking the expression you provide.

Comment: To give a chance for other users to add an answer if they think they have something more to add :-)

Comment: You should also consider simplifying the example data. The docstring would be more readable if you changed the newlines to regular spaces.